# can a jms inbound gateway reply include all messages of a message sequence

Tags: spring-integration

I have a jms-inbound-gateway that reads requests from a WebsphereMQ broker and passes them though my integration system which returns a message sequence as reply.

The message sequence is obtained by applying the splitter on a collection. It generates 63 messages as shown in the log.

The problem is that the WebsphereMQ broker only receives the last message. I have no idea where the other 62 messages went.

Is it because the jms-inbound-gateway cannot reply a message sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct; a gateway is for simple request/reply scenarios.

<s>However, I would expect the first, not the last message to be the reply.</s>

To return multiple messages for a single reply, you can either aggregate them into a single message, or use a `message-driven-channel-adapter` for inbound and `outbound-channel-adapter` for the sequence of "replies".

**EDIT**:

When a gateway receives multiple responses to a request, the one that is returned depends on the topology of the flow. With a completely synchronous flow (`DirectChannel`s throughout), the last message will be returned. With an asynchronous flow (`QueueChannel`s or `ExecutorChannel`s in the flow), it will most likely be the first, but there is a race condition.

Bottom line is the gateway only expects one reply and sending multiple replies to a single request will not produce the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you Gary. As usual, you're a big help.

Comment: I verified the headers of the returned message: sequenceSize=63 and sequenceNumber=63.

Comment: Thanks; I did some testing and have edited the answer.